# Interpreting just the missing information alone as a dummy variable R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, dummy-variable, data-preprocessing

In the sample data frame below (the original consists of thousands of rows and hundreds of columns), some values in Date1 and Date2 are unknown, and they need not be related:

```
Data_Frame <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10"), 
                         
                         Date1 = c("2010-08-03", "2012-11-28", "2009-12-13", "2000-01-15", "2003-03-01", "2015-05-09", "2020-07-11", "unknown", "2011-01-04", "unknown"),
                         
                         Value = c(2.86, 3.43, 4.65, 6.91, -2.22, 9.92, 23.41, -0.032, 8.84, 10.11),
                         
                         Date2 = c("unknown", "2015-10-22", "2019-02-14", "2010-11-25", "unknown", "2017-03-12", "2019-09-12", "unknown", "2021-05-14", "2012-08-20"))
```

I want to avoid imputation, since it will generate many artifical date values. Also, in order to avoid creating dummy variables for each date values in a column (they are in thousands and the size of the data frame will rapidly increase), does it make sense creating two columns, where 1 is an entry for all the date values which are not unknown and 0 for unknown values and vice versa in the second column, like below:

```
Data_Frame <- add_column(Data_Frame, Date11 = ifelse(Data_Frame$Date1 != 'unknown', 1, 0), .after = "Date1")
Data_Frame <- add_column(Data_Frame, Date12 = ifelse(Data_Frame$Date1 == 'unknown', 1, 0), .after = "Date11")

Data_Frame <- add_column(Data_Frame, Date21 = ifelse(Data_Frame$Date2 != 'unknown', 1, 0), .after = "Date2")
Data_Frame <- add_column(Data_Frame, Date22 = ifelse(Data_Frame$Date2 == 'unknown', 1, 0), .after = "Date21")
```

which gives

[image]

Does it make sense to use Date11, Date12, Date21 and Date22 and drop Date1 and Date2 rather in the analysis? I believe this is wrong. How can such an issue be handled, if only one level in a factor column, for example, must be treated to generate a dummy variable and not all entries (to avoid additional columns) during data-preprocessing to avoid information loss?

Answer (score 0):

You could process all `"^Date"` columns at once. The `+(.)` coerces the logical result to integer, you could also say `as.integer(.)` though.

```
res <- data.frame(Data_Frame, 
                  +(Data_Frame[grep('^Date', names(Data_Frame))] == 'unknown'))
res
#     ID      Date1  Value      Date2 Date1.1 Date2.1
# 1   A1 2010-08-03  2.860    unknown       0       1
# 2   A2 2012-11-28  3.430 2015-10-22       0       0
# 3   A3 2009-12-13  4.650 2019-02-14       0       0
# 4   A4 2000-01-15  6.910 2010-11-25       0       0
# 5   A5 2003-03-01 -2.220    unknown       0       1
# 6   A6 2015-05-09  9.920 2017-03-12       0       0
# 7   A7 2020-07-11 23.410 2019-09-12       0       0
# 8   A8    unknown -0.032    unknown       1       1
# 9   A9 2011-01-04  8.840 2021-05-14       0       0
# 10 A10    unknown 10.110 2012-08-20       1       0
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach to generate columns at once.